# Why is my app icon showing as blank from the app grid list with android studio?

Tags: java, android, icons, android-launcher

I have tried a many different links on here to figure out why my app will not show on the list of app when I download it, but I have had no luck. I have tried many different things. Is there something I am missing with getting Intent Filters set up in android studio?

```
<application
        android:name=".GdpApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBarOrangeMain">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBarSplash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but it does seem strange that you have 2

"android.intent.action.MAIN"

Comment: True, I am not sure how that happened. But I did remove the one on Main Activity and it didn't change anything. It won't let me remove the one under splash.